# How to find current in this circuit passing through 4ohm resistor

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, register, circuit-theory, circuits

Below I have added my solution after the question so please let me know how I can solve it after the last step:

[image]

These  steps to follow to solve the question from where i left in my post ,

[image: solution steps from where i left in the question]

FYI :As the registance values are in killo ohm so current will be in mill amp and power will be milli watt .

Thanks a lot  to @g36, @jasen  and @rabi for your help  . i learned something new today and its really going to help me in solving circuits easily.

Comment: Are all resistors in Ohm? or in kOhm's?

Comment: You are rights its all it Kohm so the answer will be 100milli Watt

Comment: So, the current must also be in mA.

Comment: Yes i am updating the answer now

Comment: But do not repeat such a stupid mistake on the exam. Otherwise, you're gonna fail the exam.

Comment: Yes i will keep that in mind ,thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 2):

Try to redraw it this way next time:

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frtdRT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice how I mark the same node with different colors to see what is connected to what.

Also, notice that we can skip the left \$ 12\Omega\$ resistor (R1) because it is connected directly across the voltage source

So we are left with this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHvsh1.png)</sup>

Comment: Got that thanks i understood the quick process now ,learnt something new thanks a lot.i updated my post with my answer now please check once.

Answer (score 1):

In your last circuit the top and bottom 12 ohm resistors are in parallel.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3YSVA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You're nearly there.

Comment: What about that wire ,i mean thats confusing me

Comment: Which wire do you mean?

Comment: I got that after seeing the attached image in your post. Really learnt fron you  how to solve quickly and in less step .thanks a lot. Please check my answer once  i updated it in the post now.

Answer (score 0):

This will be your next simplified circuit. Now find the current through 3 ohms resistor. Then use parallel technique to find current in 4 ohms in your previous circuit.
[image]

Comment: Thats going to make the process lengthy as it will create 3 equations cant it be solved in another better way